# uninitialized constant Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sorcery

I try to test the login methods for sorcery gem and i get an error.
I user factory girl for factories in my rspec tests.
All i want to do is to add a before method that logs me in, and after that i want to test the actions for my controller.

My spec_helper.rb

```
require 'factory_girl'

require_relative '../spec/factories/blog.rb'
require_relative '../spec/factories/user.rb'
require_relative '../spec/factories/category.rb'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller, type: :controller
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Integration, type: :feature
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

my rails_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

the error i get when i run my rspec

```
Running: spec
/home/user/work/project_name/spec/spec_helper.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller (NameError)
```

My work environment:

```
Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3, rspec - rails 3.3, sorcery 0.8.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after hours of pain.

The problem was that for sorcery version 0.8.2 you need to add to spec_helper.rb the following code:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
 .................................(other stuff)
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails
 ..........................(other stuff)
end
```

and after that use in your specs

```
@user = User.create
login_user(@user)
```